# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS -- error in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        Account_id, A_date, amount
    FROM 
        table1
    WHERE
        A_date IN (SELECT MAX(A_date), Account_id 
                   FROM table1 
                   WHERE Account_id IN (3,4,8,9) 
                   GROUP BY id)
        AND Account_id IN (3,4,8,9)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, A_date)+2, 0)) AS DATE),
        Account_id, amount
    FROM 
        cte
    WHERE
        Account_id IN (3,4,8,9)
        AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
)
INSERT INTO table1
    SELECT * 
    FROM cte
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                      FROM table1 AS t1 
                      WHERE t1.Account_id = cte.Account_id 
                        AND t1.A_date = cte.A_date)
    ORDER BY Account_id, A_date DESC
```

When I run this query I am getting the below error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

I figured its because I am using more than one id number in the subquery of the where clause. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first subquery would generate this error message:

```
SELECT Account_id, A_date, amount
FROM table1
WHERE A_date IN (SELECT MAX(A_date), Account_id
                 FROM table1
                 WHERE Account_id IN (3,4,8,9)
                 GROUP BY id
                ) AND
      Account_id IN (3,4,8,9);
```

The proper way to express this query is using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT Account_id, A_date, amount
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE A_date IN (SELECT MAX(A_date)
                 FROM table1 t1a
                 WHERE t1a.Account_id = t1.Account_id
                ) AND
      Account_id IN (3,4,8,9);
```

Note that the `group by` clause is not being used in the subquery (and the `select` has only one column).

I'm not sure what the `group by id` was supposed to be doing.  But it would have also generated an error, either because `id` is not in the table or because `account_id` is in the `select`.

A simpler way to write the query is to use window functions:

```
SELECT Account_id, A_date, amount
FROM (SELECT t1.*, MAX(a_date) OVER (PARTITION BY Account_id) as as maxad
      FROM table1 t1 
     ) t1
WHERE A_date = maxad
```

Comment: I am using group by because I need the latest date associated with the id.

Comment: the first approach worked. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace ur last insert query with :

```js
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT c.* FROM cte c, table1 t1
WHERE t1.Account_id <> cte.Account_id AND t1.A_date <> cte.A_date
ORDER BY Account_id, A_date DESC
```